# Android unit test mock.get not found

Tags: android, gradle, mockito

I have upgraded android gradle  to 7.4.2 then got a UT failure:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at com.xxx.xxx$mockBuilder$5.invoke(Test.kt:113)
-
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
```

That code line 113 like below:

```
 mockBuilder<FeaturePlugin.Builder> { it.setIcon(anyInt()) }:
```

I guess need add `mock.get(anyInt())` to fix it but `mock.get` not found.

What's proper way to fix this issue?